# INSERT INTO statement in sql for xml column doesn't insert all the data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I try to put a XML in a xml data-type in SQL Server 2008.

I created a table with a xml column, created a proper schema for the column, when I try to insert a value - the query succeeds but when I select the data with a query I can see it is missing (the xml is not complete).

The syntax of the insert contains a SELECT statement which ends in

```
for xml path('TreeNode')
```

if I run that `SELECT` by itself it brings me proper full XML document unlike the data inserted.

I've read that the limitation of XML column is 2GB, I reach nowhere near that for now.

What could be the problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you **show us** the sample XML and your T-SQL statement?? Otherweise we're gazing into a crystal ball at best.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer(by mistake actually, just went through sql settings today, unrelated to this problem)
For anyone who'll run into this problem: 
in tools->options->Query results->results to grid, there is a default limitation on data retrieved as XML of 2MB, changed it to "unlimited" and it works like charm, all the insert statements were good

Thanks for your comment.